# Вызов переменной PHP из JS с помощью AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, denwer

Есть JS функция:

```
function generation() {
var str='';
return
}
```

файл с функцией находится в директории:

`C:\inetpub\generator\function.js`

Так же есть PHP переменная $str2

Файл с переменной находится на виртуальном диске локального сервера denwer: `Z:\home\generator\www\index.php`

Как с помощью AJAX запихать PHP переменную $str2 в js функцию и прировнять к $str. Или хотя бы как нибудь передать ее в JS файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим в файле индекс(могу только предполагать потому что вашего кода вообще не вижу) есть вывод str в виде json

```
<? echo json_encode(["str" => $str], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);?>
```

Теперь из JS+jQ обращаемся к индексу

```
var $str = "";
$.ajax({
    url: '/index.php',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        result = JSON.parse(data);
        $str = result.str;
    }
});
```